# How to create a new Thread to execute an Action<T>

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, action

The title pretty much says it. I have some methods that need to run on a new thread and since all the code before creating the thread is pretty much the same, I thought I would create a function that could take as a parameter the Action I need to invoke.

Problem is, I have not found how to tell the thread that it needs to execute the Action. Is that even possible? Here's a little sample code of what I'm trying to do.

```
private void ExecuteInBiggerStackThread(Action<Helper> action, Parameters parms)
{
    ParameterizedThreadStart operation = new ParameterizedThreadStart(action);// here's the mess
    Thread bigStackThread = new Thread(operation, 1024 * 1024);

    bigStackThread.Start(parms);
    bigStackThread.Join();
}
```

Regards,
seba

Comment: The stack is not bigger.  It is actually smaller on x64.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
private void ExecuteInBiggerStackThread(Action<Helper> action, Helper h)
{
    var operation = new ParameterizedThreadStart(obj => action((Helper)obj));
    Thread bigStackThread = new Thread(operation, 1024 * 1024);

    bigStackThread.Start(h);
    bigStackThread.Join();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't even bother with `ParameterizedThreadStart`.  Let the compiler do the dirty work:

```
private void ExecuteInBiggerStackThread(Action<Helper> action, Helper h)
{
    Thread bigStackThread = new Thread(() => action(h), 1024 * 1024);

    bigStackThread.Start();
    bigStackThread.Join();
}
```

Of course, you could carry this a step further and change the signature to:

```
private void ExecuteInBiggerStackThread(Action action) { ... }
```

Comment: How does the function look like if you "carry it a step further"?

Comment: Wow, this is 10 years old...  Not sure what I had in mind when I wrote that.  But these days I wouldn't even bother with this style of threading, I'd just use Tasks and async methods for the threading.

Comment: Thank you for this hint, I tried to replace Threads by Tasks and found it is working much better! Lambdas are directly supported with Tasks.

Answer (score 3):

Or a more generic version of the method....

```
protected void ExecuteInBiggerStackThread<T>(Action<T> action, T parameterObject)
{
  var bigStackThread = new Thread(() => action(parameterObject), 1024 * 1024);
  bigStackThread.Start();
  bigStackThread.Join();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `Action<object>` and then cast to `Helper` in the Action's body